# playing a local video in a uiwebview

Tags: objective-c, ipad, html, video, uiwebview

i load a local html file into an ipad application:

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"lieferant1" ofType:@"html"];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[webView loadHTMLString:content baseURL:baseURL];
```

the webpage gets displayed, content of my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>
    <video>
        <source src="banane.m4v">
    </video>
</p>
```

so, `banane.m4v` is in my root, just in some groups, but not in real directories.
[image]

but the video section in my webview keeps black. no video gets loaded. i uploaded my html file and my `.m4v` video to my webserver to check if its not encoded properly, but everything works fine, surfing the html file with my ipad.

some ideas whats wrong?

Comment: What's wrong with using the standard media playback controls? Is there other content around your video that you want to preserve?

Comment: yes, the websites are already existing. where talking about hundreds of sites, so it has to be that way. i'm trying and trying, but i can't figure out why this is not working. it should!

Comment: Have you tried to use the full path instead of just the filename and adding a file:// upfront?

Comment: you mean `<source src=" file://banane.m4v" />` ? i tried but without luck.

Comment: strange, even with a full url to my webserver it doesnt get loaded

Answer (score 9, accepted):

oh my god

```
<video controls>
    <source src="banane.m4v">
</video>
```

where `controls` is the magic word.

:X

Comment: For me, for some mp4 videos downloaded from Youtube, this method shows "play" sign crossed out for some reason

Comment: Having the same problem as Petr, can't get any .mp4's to work.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong (or silly) but, did you try `file:///banane.m4v` (Add the extra '/' for root)

Comment: yes i did. as i said, i only hat to update my html code with "controls"

Answer (score 0):

For everyone that experiences a crossed out play symbol,
When you drag your movie-files (mp4's work as well, just make sure the codec is okay - easiest way is to export for iPhone with QuickTime) a dialog appears.
Make sure you tick your app under "add to targets".

Or if you already copied your video into the project, if you click it in Xcode's file browser, you'll have an option on the right-hand side to select targets.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `allowsInlineMediaPlayback` property on the `UIWebView`:

```
[webView setAllowsInlineMediaPlayback:YES];
```