# iPhone : How to play local video in WebView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uiwebview

I want to play video in UIWebView. This video is stored in my app (It is local video not coming from server).

I dont want to use `MPMoviePlayerController`.

I got the following code from SO :

```
NSString *url = @"http://my_url.com/my_movie_path/";
UIWebView* tempAudioPlayer = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)]; 
[tempAudioPlayer loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<iframe frameborder=\"0\"    width=\"0\" height=\"0\" src=\"%@\"></iframe>", url] baseURL:nil];
[self addSubview:tempAudioPlayer];
```

But Its not working for me.

Is there any other method to play video without `MPMoviePlayerController`?

What should I do ?

Comment: DUPE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836595/playing-a-local-video-in-a-uiwebview

Comment: So is the other, try setting your basepath for the uiwebview.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
NSString *Str = @"<video controls> <source src=\"yourvideofile.mp4\"> </video>";
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourvideofile" ofType:@"mp4"];
[Webview loadHTMLString:Str baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
```

Comment: You can try your luck with just making new sample view base project => drag n drop webview from xib => make outlet and connect outlet and copy paste code provided above change file name. It will take only few mins. And if don't work with webview first try that MOV file with MPMoviePlayer to check file and resolution is ok with iphone.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below link if it works....

http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/02/youtube-apis-iphone-cool-mobile-apps.html

This will guide you how to play videos from local storage..

Try to attach video in HTML string with local path as URL... (only hint) i have not tried but will be good reference to try....  use other (**dh14-sl's**) **strong text** answer also as reference to create HTML string